# How to randomly select number of rows based on conditions in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to randomly select 50 rows from one sheet and pasting them in a separate workbook for data sampling. I don't know how to do it because first, I'm new to VBA, I want to learn something new and second, I tried searching this on Google but no accurate answer found.

So what's on my mind is this:

1. I'll get first the number of rows in that worksheet. I've already
   done it with this one line of code:
   `CountRows = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
2. Get a random number from 1 to `CountRows` uniquely. The random numbers should be incremental (1,5,7,20,28,30,50 and no backward counting). Then grab that row, create a new workbook if not yet open and paste it there.

How can I achieve this process? I have no idea how to start this.

Comment: But how? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do what you need.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim tempArr() As String
    Dim srcWB As Workbook, destWB As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Const rowMax As Long = 100 'maximum number of rows in source sheet
    Const rowMin As Long = 1   'starting row number to copy
    Const rowCopy As Long = 50 'number of rows to copy
    Dim intArr(1 To rowCopy) As Integer, rowArr(1 To rowCopy) As Integer
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook

    'get unique random numbers in dictionary
    With dict
        Do While .Count < rowCopy
            lng = Rnd * (rowMax - rowMin) + rowMin
            .Item(lng) = Empty
        Loop
        tempArr = Split(Join(.Keys, ","), ",")
    End With

    'convert random numbers to integers
    For i = 1 To rowCopy
        intArr(i) = CInt(tempArr(i - 1))
    Next i

    'sort random numbers
    For i = 1 To rowCopy
        rowArr(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(intArr, i)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(rowArr(i))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(rowArr(i)))
        End If
    Next i

    'copy random rows, change sheet name and destination path as required
    Set destWB = Workbooks.Add
    With destWB
        rng.Copy destWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .SaveAs Filename:="D:\Book2.xls", FileFormat:=56
    End With
End Sub
```

Above code uses Dictionary so you have to add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Type Library. In Visual Basic Editor, go to ***Tools->References*** and check ***"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"*** in the list.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

First, generate an array of 50 unique numbers between 1 and CountRows, using this routine:

```
' Generate a sorted array(0 to count-1) numbers between a and b inclusive
Function UniqueRandom(ByVal count As Long, ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
  ReDim arr(b - a) As Long

  Randomize
  For i = 0 To b - a:    arr(i) = a + i:     Next
  If b - a < count Then UniqueRandom = arr:    Exit Function

  For i = 0 To b - a    'Now we shuffle the array
    j = Int(Rnd * (b - a))
    x = arr(i):   arr(i) = arr(j):   arr(j) = x    ' swap
  Next

  ' After shuffling the array, we can simply take the first portion
  ReDim Preserve arr(0 To count - 1)

  'sorting, probably not necessary
  For i = 0 To count - 1
    For j = i To count - 1
      If arr(j) < arr(i) Then x = arr(i):   arr(i) = arr(j):   arr(j) = x   ' swap
    Next
  Next

  UniqueRandom = arr
End Function
```

Now you can use the above routine to generate random, unique and sorted indexes and copy the corresponding rows. Here's an example:

```
Sub RandomSamples()
  Const sampleCount As Long = 50
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, ar() As Long, rngToCopy As Range

  With Sheet1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    ar = UniqueRandom(sampleCount, 1, lastRow)
    Set rngToCopy = .Rows(ar(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
      Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, .Rows(ar(i)))
    Next
  End With
  With Workbooks.Add
    rngToCopy.Copy .Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "samples.xlsx"
    .Close False
  End With
End Sub
```